# I have used this code for text to speech via pyttx3 and get this error I dont know how to solve it

Tags: python

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Error:

```
return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 1863, in <module>
    ISpeechWaveFormatEx._methods_ = [
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\Karan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 125, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Answer (score 0):

just use downgrade python version like 3.8.0 or before

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
pip install pyttsx3==2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install pyttsx3 using "pip install pyttsx3==2.71" it works.